# Python & PyQt5 : How to get RGB color values of a frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, rgb

I'm trying to build an PyQt5 application about getting RGB values of your selected color. I have written a code that you can select a color and I can display the color in a frame;

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QPushButton,QFrame,QColorDialog,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

class TutorialWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        selected_color = QColor(0,0,255)
        self.button = QPushButton("Choose color",self)
        self.button.move(25,25)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showColorDialog)

        self.frame= QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" %selected_color.name())
        self.frame.setGeometry(150,22,50,50)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,200)

    def showColorDialog(self):
        selected_color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if selected_color.isValid():
            self.frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" %selected_color.name())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pprint("input parameters = " + str(sys.argv))
    tutorial_window = TutorialWindow()
    tutorial_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I want one more thing. As you see, after you run and select your color; I want to print frame's color's RGB values. How can I add this to my code?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "print the frame's RGB values", but surely the easiest way to access the color of the frame is to read your `selected_color` variable ?

To simply print the RGB values to the terminal, the following will suffice:

```py
    def showColorDialog(self):
        # get color from user
        selected_color = QColorDialog.getColor(self.selected_color, self)
        # did user cancel operation ?
        if not selected_color.isValid():
            return
        # update stylesheet
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "QWidget { background-color: %s}" % selected_color.name())
        # grab RBG values and print them to terminal
        rgb = (selected_color.red(),
               selected_color.green(),
               selected_color.blue())
        print(rgb)
        # set `selected_color`as an instance variable so you can retrieve it later
        self.selected_color = selected_color
```

If you want to display them in the Gui, just replace the `QFrame` with a `QLabel`, and use `self.frame.setText(str(rgb))` instead of `print`.

If you want the RGB values formatted into a single hexadecimal value string, you can instead use something like :

```py
rgb_hex_str = f"#{selected_color.rgb():x}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching something like:

```
yourWidget.palette().highlight().color().name()
```

to get RGB:

```
yourWidget.palette().highlight().color().getRgb())
```

Comment: In python conversion between hex and 'rgb' is also included in the plotting package matplotlib. import matplotlib.colors as colors,then :
colors.hex2color('#ffffff')        #==> (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
colors.rgb2hex((1.0, 1.0, 1.0))    #==> '#ffffff' @Wicaledon

Comment: I added `print(self.frame.palette().highlight().color().getRgb())` but when I select fully white color, it shows (0, 120, 215, 255)